# How to query array list data from mongodb?

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb

how to query the data if COLOUR_ID is an array list?

`***{"jtis_journey_time" : {"COLOUR_ID" :{0:2}}}***`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use array like this

{ COLOUR_ID : { $in : [1,2,3,4] } }

Comment: I just want to get the first element and i can't include all possible value.